# How create raw socket in Linux without buffering receive packets? Is it possible?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I use Linux, and I have created an application that uses raw sockets. When I open it and `recv(...)`, I get packets, which went earlier, and I guess were buffered in kernel, or network card driver. But I don't need them. I need only packets, which went after I opened the socket.

Of course, I can drop these packets, but I don't know how many packets I need drop, because each time quantity of packets is different.

How can I create this socket? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you've negotiated the host/port to communicate on, and do you have control over whatever is sending these packets?

You could:

1) Immediately after opening the socket, do a recv() loop (with flags=MSG_DONTWAIT) and ignore every packet assuming that it was stale, ending the loop as soon as recv() returns <=0 bytes (it should set errno to EWOULDBLOCK to indicate that there was nothing left to read too, otherwise the cause could be another socket-related issue)

2) Negotiate a new port each time

3) Add a custom header to your packets (e.g. first N bits) to indicate e.g. sequence number, or a special "new connection" code, or a timestamp. This usage really depends on what you're doing on both ends of this raw socket.

Comment: Thank you. I can't control incoming packets, and I can't custom header of packet. First recomendation is good. How can I get stale? It will be all packets until recv will not return EWOULDBLOCK? And what does mean negotiate? (I'm beginner in English and sometimes can't understand special terms). I thought may be there is  means like ioctl(...) or setsockopts(...) or something else.

Comment: Yes - all packets until recv(..., MSG_DONTWAIT) returns <=0 (at which point errno should == EWOULDBLOCK to indicate that there's nothing left in the socket, other errno values would indicate a real failure/error).

Comment: And by "negotiate" i meant that you could have the 2 applications decide on the port to use each time before sending real data - e.g. first send packets on a known port with "please talk to me on port X", then the real communication happens on that port. But given your additional information of "I can't control incoming packets, and I can't custom header of packet" I don't believe you'd be able to do this as it requires that you have control of both ends of the communication.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try with EWOULDBLOCK, I can't negotiate two applications. I have only packets from network, a lot of packets.